# Tiling a rectangle with squares

Tags: real-analysis, recreational-mathematics, tiling

Recently, the German science journal Spektrum put online a [riddle](https://www.spektrum.de/raetsel/wie-gross-ist-der-flaecheninhalt-des-rechtecks/2028595) about squares being tiled to a rectangle:

[image]

The task was to determine the area of the rectangle tiled with $8$ squares, of which the middle square has area $1$.

Note that two pairs of squares each have identical side length.

**Questions.**

1. For what integers $n > 1$ is there a rectangle with real-valued size lengths such that the rectangle can be tiled by $n$ squares with pairwise distinct side lengths?
2. For what integers $n > 2$ is there a rectangle with real-valued size lengths such that the rectangle can be tiled by $n$ squares so that the squares have at least $n - 1$ different side lengths? (That is at most $2$ squares involved in the tiling have identical side length.)

Only one questions needs to be answered for acceptance.

Comment: Answer to Q2: Every natural n works.

Comment: For Q1, probably all $n\ge9$. See, e.g., https://oeis.org/A002839 – the keyphrase is "squared rectangles".